# App that runs in background and injects touches to springboard without private API or jailbreaking

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, springboard

I am trying to write an app that runs in the background and injects touches to the springboard or other apps. I cannot use any private API and no jailbreaking. The app needs to be approved for the AppStore.

I would appreciate if you could suggest a few tutorials or examples for the above mentioned problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: "Injects touches to the springboard" what are you actually trying to do? This would be considered malicious and would never be aproved.

Comment: This is hopeless without jailbreaking.

Comment: Well.Here inject means injecting code or you want to automate touch events of spring board?

Comment: If this *could* be done for AppStore, everyone would just have Androids.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There is no public API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is against Apple's own rules. You can't push such an app to AppStore.